# sql like with another table

Tags: sql, sql-like

[image: example]

I have two tables, in first have: value1, value2, value3
Second: I have full address

How can I use query like:

`select * from table2 where address like 
  '%table1.value1%table1.value2%table1.value3%'`

Comment: You want to concatenate strings (`'%' || table1.value1 || '%' || table1.value2 || '%' || table1.value3' || '%'` in standard SQL). Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think `exists` does what you want:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t2.address like concat('%', t1.value1, '%', t1.value2, '%', t1.value3, '%')
             );
```

That said, the need to do this suggests something wrong with your data model.

Comment: `sql like` you Gordon, it likes you a lot +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this?

```
select * from table2 where address like '%table1.value1%' OR address like '%table1.value2%' OR address like '%table1.value3%'
```

But i think your datamodel should be normalized (2NF & 3NF).

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP` can be used to match the contents of table1 with table2.

```
select address, value1, value2, value3
from table1, table2 
where 
address REGEXP value1 and
address REGEXP value2 and
address REGEXP value3;
```

I feel that `like` would be better used if you needed to match a hard-coded value:

```
select address from table1 where address like '%staticvalue%'
```

See an implemented example at [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h4SdnQg1nYwfkNx2NLypq/0)